# Show square form of symmetrical Matrix is $\geq 1$ as long as the smalles Eigenvalue of the Matrix is 1

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A$ be a symmetrical Matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n*n}$. Also note that $q_A(x) := x^\top Ax$. We know that $\|x\| = 1$. Show that $q_A(x) \geq 1 $ if the smallest Eigenvalue of $A$ is $1$.

What I know thus far:
I know this holds up if we assume x is an Eigenvector of $A$, since then $Ax = \lambda x$ and therefore $q_A(x) := x^\top Ax = x^\top \lambda x = 1 * \lambda$.
This however does not hold for vectors that are not Eigenvectors of $A$, which is where my problem lies.

Comment: Hint: Eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix are orthogonal and form a basis.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I dont quite understand how i would use this in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose an orthogonal matrix $S \in \mathbb{R}^{n*n}$ such that $A = S^{-1}DS$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix containing all the eigenvalues $(\lambda_j)_{1 \leq j \leq n}$ (which we know are real) of $A$. Now let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be arbitrary and have norm $1$ and $Sx := (s_j)_{1 \leq j \leq n}$. Therefore
$$
x^\top Ax = (Sx)^\top D Sx = \sum_{j = 1}^n s_j^2\lambda_j \underbrace{\geq}_{\lambda_j \geq 1 } \sum_{j = 1}^n s_j^2 = \lVert Sx \rVert^2 = \lVert x \rVert^2 = 1
$$
where in the second to last step we used that orthogonal transformations preserve the euclidian norm.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch: First, recall that symmetric matrices have orthonormal eigenbases and real eigenvalues.  In other words, there is a basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ of eigenvectors such that $\|v_i\|=1$ and $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle=0$ if $i\not=j$.

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.  Then, we can write $x=\sum c_iv_i$.  It then follows that $\|x\|^2=\sum c_i^2=1$.  On the other hand, $Ax=\sum c_i\lambda_iv_i$ and $x^TAx=\sum c_i^2\lambda_i$.  Now, use the assumption that every $\lambda_i\geq 1$.